# How to implement a "task monitor" with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to execute some tasks in the server and show status with JSF (primefaces).

Below I'm describing my last try:

**default.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton 
    value="execute" 
    action="#{controller.init()}" /> <!-- initialize and validate data and call task1()  -->

<p:fieldset id="messages" legend="Status:">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="msg1" styleClass="#{controller.status1}">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{controller.msg1}" />
                <span class="#{controller.classToIconClass(controller.status1)}"></span>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="msg2" styleClass="#{controller.status2}">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{controller.msg2}" />
                <span class="#{controller.classToIconClass(controller.status2)}"></span>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </li>
...
    <p:remoteCommand name="task1" action="#{controller.task1()}" update="messages" />
    <p:remoteCommand name="task2" action="#{controller.task2()}" update="messages" />
```

**Each step is like this: (Controller.java)**

```
@SessionScoped
...
    public void task1() {
        if(stopExecution) return;
        long returnCode = -1;
        String errorMessage = "An error occurred in the task1 execution.";
        try {
            returnCode = execute(comandString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error(errorMessage, e);
            returnCode = -1;
            stopExecution = true;
        }

        if(returnCode != 0 && returnCode != 4) {
            msg1 = errorMessage;
            status1 = "error";
            stopExecution = true;
            return;
        } else {
            msg1 = "Task1 is finished.";
            status1 = "successful";
        }

        msg2 = "Running task2...";
        status2 = "running";

        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.execute("task2();"); // Calls next step
    }

    // Everything is like task1() and always call next task at the end:
    public void task2() {...}
    public void task3() {...}
    public void task4() {...}
    public void finish() {...}
```

This way everything runs fine, but the users sometimes refresh the page and the execution chain brokes.

Is there a way to do what a I want to do and surviving a page refresh?

PS:
I also tried to execute task by task with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:messages");` between them, but the page only updates at the end of the last task.

**EDIT:**

As Michele and Xtreme Biker said, I do it in a separate thread:

**Controller.java**

```
@SessionScoped

...

RequestContext requestContext;

Callable<Long> task1 = new Callable<Long>() {

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        long returnCode = -1;
        String errorMessage = "An error occurred in the task1 execution.";

        returnCode = execute(comandString);

        if(returnCode != 0 && returnCode != 4) {
            msg1 = errorMessage;
            status1 = "error";
            return returnCode;
        } else {
            msg1 = "Task1 is finished.";
            status1 = "successful";
            msg2 = "Running task2...";
            status2 = "running";
        }

        requestContext.update("form:messages");

        return returnCode;
    }
};

public void init() {
    requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    List<Future<Long>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<Long>>();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    tasks.add(executor.submit(this.task1));
    tasks.add(executor.submit(this.task2));
    tasks.add(executor.submit(this.task3));
    tasks.add(executor.submit(this.task4));
    tasks.add(executor.submit(this.finish));

    executor.shutdown();
}
```

All tasks run even if I do a page refresh, good.
But the view doesn't update.

I think that `requestContext.update("form:messages");` is in the wrong place.
But if a get `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()` from inside the Callable.call, I get a NullPointerException, because I'm not in the JSF life cycle.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: The only way to make it survive a page refresh is doing it in Session scope. Do your work in a bean and access its state from the view.

Comment: if these are long running tasks, you should use an `Executor` to run them async from page communication, and implement your controller to monitor a `List` of `Future`. nevetheless, the best way is to use a `MessageDrivenBean`, but i've never implemented such a mechanism, so it's just theory

Comment: @XtremeBiker, it's already `@SessionScoped` _(edited my question)_ It keep my "status" but the execution chain brokes.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, I have another program that I use EJB's `@Asynchronous` with Future. I was expecting for a simple JSF solution to do that. But seems that it's not too easy, I'll try what you said. _I need to deliver this today_ =(

Comment: As @MicheleMariotti says, you need to delegate the job to another thread. If you do it in the one of the request as you seem to be doing, the execution could stop if you don't wait the whole request/response http cycle. That's basic http matter.

Comment: I updated my question.
All the tasks run fine, but the page doesn't update.
Please, can you check my updated Controller.java?

Comment: i am not sure if this is somehow related, but aren't people reloading because the page itself does not reload? Do you think something like p:poll could be used to periodically update some parts of the screen using ajax?

Comment: Yes, I delivered today with p:poll. It's Ok.
But seems that it's impossible to update from outside the "request flow" of JSF, at least using the core of primefaces...I was a little disappointed...
Only to know: I replaced all of `ExecutorService` stuff by `@Asynchronous` and it behaved in the same way, but looking better.
Thanks for all.

Comment: i'm glad you made it!

two points to complete the topic: 1. you can't access RequestContext from Callables because it is destroyed when your request ends, and it ends before Callable returns.
2. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756945/jsf-primefaces-progressbar-update-value-while-action-method-is-running/22757321#22757321) for a hack that you can combine with async execution. a little effort is needed to autostart the progressbar on page refresh (when processing has been started already), but it's not so hard.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti, thanks. I don't know if I'll have some time to test it now, but seems like a solution.
I'm not sure, but it's a good idea to compile these comments in an answer?